# What is the name of this button?

Tags: ipad, ios, keyboard, ui

I've been calling it the "keyboard dismissal button," but I'd like to know if it has an actual name.

[image: keyboard dismissal button]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Turn on voice over in accessibility and when you click it it will speak what it is called.

It's called "hide keyboard" using voiceover, but it could be called something different within apple, because what voiceover reads could be a label set just for voiceover.

Comment: Aha, I totally forgot that I could have used VoiceOver. That works for me, thanks!

Comment: how can i hide keyboard by command and tap into this button because hide.keyboard(); is not working for me !